# Adding the first word from header to all the subsequent lines of file using awk

Tags: awk

I've a file with header records followed by detail lines. I would like have the word from header tagged to the subsequent lines within the file using awk.. each Header record has a specific word 'header' in it.

My sample file is

```
h1_val  header
this is line 1 under header set1
this is line 2 under header set1
this is line 3 under header set1
this is line 4 under header set1
h2_val  header
this is line 1 under header set2
this is line 2 under header set2
this is line 3 under header set2
this is line 4 under header set2
```

My output should be like

```
h1_val this is line 1 under header set1
h1_val this is line 2 under header set1
h1_val this is line 3 under header set1
h1_val this is line 4 under header set1
h2_val this is line 1 under header set2
h2_val this is line 2 under header set2
h2_val this is line 3 under header set2
h2_val this is line 4 under header set2
```

Please help

Thanks!!!

Thanks ghoti it seems to be working fine if the lines are plain.. 
If my input looks like comma delimited and with double quotes... what variation should the awk be

```
"h1_val","header word" 
"this is line 1","under header","set1" 
"this is line 2","under header","set1" 
"this is line 2","under header","set1" 
"this is line 2","under header","set1" 
"h2_val","header word" 
"this is line 1","under header","set2" 
"this is line 2","under header","set2" 
"this is line 2","under header","set2" 
"this is line 2","under header","set2"
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Why didn't you specify those conditions in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do it.

```
$ awk '$2=="header"{h=$1;next} {printf("%s ",h)} 1' input.txt
h1_val this is line 1 under header set1
h1_val this is line 2 under header set1
h1_val this is line 3 under header set1
h1_val this is line 4 under header set1
h2_val this is line 1 under header set2
h2_val this is line 2 under header set2
h2_val this is line 3 under header set2
h2_val this is line 4 under header set2
```

Or if you prefer, this is just about functionally equivalent:

```
$ awk '$2=="header"{h=$1;next} {print h OFS $0}' input.txt
```

Note that these imply that your header text has no spaces.  If it does, then you may need to do something fancier than `$2=="header"` to find your headers.  If this is the case, then please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11424847/edit) with more detail.

Comment: Thanks ghoti it seems to be working fine if the lines are plain..

If my input looks like comma delimited and with double quotes... what variation should the awk be

"h1_val","header word" 
"this is line 1","under header","set1" 
"this is line 2","under header","set1" 
"this is line 2","under header","set1" 
"this is line 2","under header","set1" 
"h2_val","header word" 
"this is line 1","under header","set2" 
"this is line 2","under header","set2" 
"this is line 2","under header","set2" 
"this is line 2","under header","set2" 

Thanks!!

Comment: As I hinted in my answer, you should click the [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11424847/edit) link under your question and update your question with more details, if there are details that will improve the answers you're getting.  StackOverflow comments do terrible formatting.  Please update your question, and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh, I'll mention that comma+quote delimited text is unlikely to be handled perfectly by awk.  If commas are your field delimiter, awk doesn't know the difference between a comma inside vs. outside the quotes.  Of course, if you have no commas inside quotes, you should be fine.

Comment: I've tried like this... but it does not add comma after the first word...Any input is appreciated..Thanks!!                                                    awk -F, '$2=="\"header word\""{h=$1;next} {printf("%s ",h)} 1' input.txt

Comment: Finally this has solved it....awk -F, '$2=="\"header word\""{h=$1;next} {printf("%s,",h)} 1' input.txt

Answer (score 2):

```
> awk '{if($2=="header")p=$1;else print p,$0}' temp2
h1_val this is line 1 under header set1
h1_val this is line 2 under header set1
h1_val this is line 3 under header set1
h1_val this is line 4 under header set1
h2_val this is line 1 under header set2
h2_val this is line 2 under header set2
h2_val this is line 3 under header set2
h2_val this is line 4 under header set2
```